# proving uniform convergence of function series from pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $  f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb R $ be a sequence of derivable functions 
 with $|f_n'(x)|<3$ $\forall x\in[0,1]$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb N$.

Assume that the series is pointwise converge to $L(x)$ on $[0,1]$. Prove that the series is uniformly converge to $L(x)$ in $[0,1]$.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or this: [Uniformly bounded derivative implies uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/875182/42969).

Comment: When you write "series", do you mean "sequence"?